# Use the Archimedean Property to Prove the Value of the Infimum of a Set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Define the set $$T=\lbrace \frac{m-n}{m+n} : m,n\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace$$

Where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers, starting from 1.

Use the Archimedean Property to prove that the infimum of this set $T$ is $-1$ (and similarly the supremum is 1).

I find this problem to be really tricky to approach since there are two variables.  Although I can get an intuitive feel as to why the infimum and supremum are what they are, I'm really having trouble formalizing it.  How would you prove this?

Comment: I think you forgot to add a condition that $m$ and $n$ should be both $>0$ otherwise $-1=\frac{0-1}{0+1}$ is a minimum of $T$ and the Archimedean Property is not so interesting here.

Comment: In the context of this problem, $\mathbb{N}$ refers to the set {$1,2,3,...$}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $ \frac{m-n}{m+n} >-1$ for any m, n $\in \mathbb{ N} $, the infimum of T is greater than or equal to -1. 
Choose $m, n  \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ \frac{m}{n} < \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$ using Archimedean property( where $ \epsilon$  is an arbitrary positive number less than 1)

$\Rightarrow 0 <2m < (\epsilon +1)m + \epsilon n$

$\Rightarrow -m -n <m -n < -m - n + \epsilon (m +n) $

$ \Rightarrow -1 < \frac{m-n}{m+n} < -1+ \epsilon $

So, by the definition of infimum, the infimum of T is 1

Now, for the supremum of T -

Since $ \frac{m-n}{m+n} <1 $   $\forall m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, hence the supremum of T is less than or equal to 1.

Also, for any $ 0 <\epsilon <1 $, by Archimedean property, choose $m, n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that

$\frac {n}{m} < \frac{\epsilon}{2 - \epsilon} $
$\Rightarrow (1-\epsilon)(m+n) < m -n$
$\Rightarrow (1-\epsilon)(m+n) < m-n <m+n$
$\Rightarrow 1-\epsilon < \frac{m-n}{m+n} <1$

And hence by the definition of supremum, the supremum of T is 1